# how to call upon csv file on pandas python using words

Tags: python, pandas

Just to simplified the problem I make a list of fruits, how I ranked them and their colour, and I want to call them with their name.

```
import pandas as pd

Data = pd.read_csv("Fruits.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(Data)
Fruits = int(input("Insert fruit name: "))
print(df.loc[Fruits])
```

And here is the csv file

```
Fruit,Rating,Colour
Apple, 5/10, Red
Banana, 7/10, Yellow
Grapes, 10/10, Purple
Orange, 9/10, Orange
```

When I run the program, when I put in the number 0 in it,

```
Insert fruit name: 0
Fruit     Apple
Rating     5/10
Colour      Red
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

And I dont want that, I want when I put

```
Insert fruit name: Apple
Fruit     Apple
Rating     5/10
Colour      Red
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `rename`:

```
import pandas as pd

Data = pd.read_csv("Fruits.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(Data)
Fruits = input("Insert fruit name: ")
print(df.loc[df['Fruit'] == Fruits].rename(None))
```

Comment: ```Insert fruit name: Apple
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Tellvon\apple.py", line 5, in <module>

    Fruits = int(input())

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Apple'```

Comment: hmm its written must pass an index to rename

Comment: @JustinHabelKiswanto Try Inputing `apple`, it works

Comment: just one thing, for future user who make something like this, remove the .loc, and .rename(None))